# Graphing rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Graph the rational function $f(x)=\frac{-4}{-x-2}$

Please help me figure out how to start this problem.

Comment: I assumed that everything to the right of the `/` was part of the denominator of the rational function when I typeset your question.  Please verify that this assumption is correct.

Comment: It's correct. Thank you lots!

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please explain what you have already tried and what you are having trouble with.

$ \textbf{Hint:} $ Find the domain of $f(x)$. Are there any discontinuities? Vertical? Horizontal? What is the limiting behavior the function? (i.e. what does the function do as $x$ gets really large, or really small?)

Answer (score 1):

Start submitting values for x and calculate f(x)

f(0)=4/2=2

f(1)=4/3=1.3

f(2)=4/4=1

f(3)=4/5=0.8

f(4)=4/6=0.67

f(5)=4/7=0.57

and so on and so forth.

If you start plotting, you would realize that f(x) is close to zero but is never zero. If f(x) were on the y-axis, then this is how the graph would look like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how a rectangulay hyperbola $xy=k$ looks like? For positive k, it looks like (http://intmstat.com/plane-analytic-geometry/xyis1.gif)

Edit:
 $f(x)=\frac{-4}{-x-2}=\frac{4}{x+2}$
My link already shows how to plot $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Npw to plot, $f(x)==\frac{1}{x+2}$
, pretend that the X=-2 line is the real Y axis, and plot the original graph. (Now change the graph slightly to get $f(x)=\frac{4}{x+2}$.)

Comment: I don't know what a rectangular hyperbola looks like and the link says the page can't be found but I think if I can see what it looks like I may be able to figure it out.

Comment: @user160196, the new link might work better.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you explain how I should make a shift of the axes?

Comment: Check edited version.

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of confused on what the graph is supposed to look like..

Comment: Exactly like the one shown in the picture. But, to control for (x) being replaced by (x+2), pretend that the X=-2 line is the real Y axis, and plot the graph in the link provided.